# MySQL: Check if var exists in one of two tables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using PDO. There is the variable $name and I want to know if it exists in table_1 or table_2

```
SELECT id, name FROM table_1 WHERE name = :name
SELECT id, name FROM table_2 WHERE name = :name
```

Can I do this by only one SQL-Query?

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:
(Not tested, but that should be the right way.)

```
SELECT 
    IF(
        (
            EXISTS(SELECT name FROM table_1 WHERE name="")
            OR
            EXISTS(SELECT name FROM table_2 WHERE name="")
        ), 1, 0) AS nameExists;
```

This returns 1 if the condition is true or false if its not.